# React Modal: Saving the Contents of the Child Best Practises

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a React component library and populating a modal (Parent) with a complex stateful component (Child). This generic modal also has a footer with a save button. The user interacts with the contents of the modal (Child) and when they are ready, they click the modal. This saves to the server, the current state of the internal component.

I'm trying to understand the best way to accomplish this in React. Right now, the child component is using useImperativeHandle to expose a getData() function that is used by the click listener callback in the parent modal who then calls the server. This feels wrong. What I'd like is the parent component to tell the child to save its contents when the user clicks on the modal save button. I don't think the modal should contain the save logic that contacts the server.

Please let me know what are the best practises for this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Agree, it does feel weird for the parent to request data from a child at the time of submit, so data ownership should either be in the parent or at a shared data source (initialized in the parent).

On the parent side, not sure of how many changes may get fired by the child (perhaps when the process is completed), but thinking you could have something like an `onStuffChanged` callback on the child that sets values in the parent to use on the submit.

On the shared data source (keeping it to React), you have a `reducer` or `context`.  `Context` might be overkill here since it's just a parent / child relationship.

Will use `reducer` as an example here, but there are many other libraries that could solve this with state management.  Basically you can pass the `dispatch` to the child and have it update the data store as needed (i.e. when it has all the data needed to submit).  The parent `submit` button can then use the data stored there.

Basically suggesting either a child callback or shared data source / state management pattern that the parent and child have access to.